# Build php event extension in docker failed: php_sockets_le_socket: symbol not found

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I want to add event extension in my [php image](https://hub.docker.com/r/salamandermh/php-cli/dockerfile), so I add these two lines to my Dockerfile

```
pecl install event && \
docker-php-ext-enable event && \
```

I have installed the `libevent`(use `libevent-dev`) dependence in my Dockerfile.

When I run the container(`docker run -it  salamandermh/php-cli:7.1 bash`), it shows the warning message: `PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/event.so' - Error relocating /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/event.so: php_sockets_le_socket: symbol not found in Unknown on line 0`

It seems `sockets` module is not found, however I can find `sockets` in `[PHP Modules]`

Comment: The link to the image doesn't work for me. Can you post your Dockerfile?

Comment: @Mihai I have changed the link, now it's valid